# Changing Scatter Plot Point Colors with many observations

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm currently doing a Principal Component Analysis on a large data set containing a lot of different cars on Craigslist. Since there are so many observations, I would like to point out some specific car brands, e.g, Mercedes-Benz, Ford, or Tesla.

I've been doing the following in ggplot2:

```
manufacturer <- data[3] #Which is the labels for the manufacturers
manu.label <- unlist(manufacturer)

ggplot(plot.car.pca, aes(SCA.PCA1, SCA.PCA2, label = manu.label, color = manu.label) + 
geom_point() + 
geom_text(aes(label = manu.label), hjust = -0.01, vjust = 0)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: Scatterplot]

As can be seen in the picture, there are a lot of manufacturers, but I am only interested in highlighting some of them e.g., the Ford car points on the scatterplot could be green, Tesla could be red, and the rest could be black points. I hope I've provided enough information and that some of you can help me here.

Comment: You could split plot.car.pca into two datasets, the first one with the manufacturers you are not interested in and the second one with the manufacturers you are interested in. Then create two geom_points in the ggplot function, and adjust sizes/colors, etc.. to your wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaboration on my comment (example with mtcars)

```
library(ggplot2)
dt <- mtcars

#create column with car name
dt$car <- rownames(dt)

#cars interested in
dt1 <- subset(dt, dt$car %in% c("Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona"))

#cars not interested in
dt2 <- subset(dt, !dt$car %in% dt1$car)

#plot with both (individual geom_points)
ggplot(dt2) + geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = mpg)) + geom_point(data = dt1, aes(x = mpg, y = mpg, colour = car)) + geom_text(data = dt1, aes(x = mpg, y = mpg, label = car), hjust = 1, vjust = 1) + theme_bw()
```